# How to get data from XBRL file FROM Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I want to read the xbrl file and extract some information.

Does anyone have experience with XBRL?

Comment: did you try https://pypi.org/project/python-xbrl/?

Comment: You need to include what you have you tried and researched so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75176592/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).